# 'card flips' using CSS flip as if the axis is off screen or the cards sit on top of each other

Tags: html, css

So I was trying to have a webpage with images that would flip to reveal text, and only the first  two images seem to work without issue. Each image to the right of those two either sit on top of each other, or once I try and space them out more, they rotate with a insanely large axis? The images should rotate on the x-axis and be evenly spaced out, but I can't work out how to space them without distorting their rotation? I'm quite new to CSS, sorry. Sorry for the huge walls of text.

```css
.flip-container {
  position: relative;
  -webkit-perspective: 1000;
  perspective: 1000;
  padding: 5px;
}

.flip-cards {
  width: 200px;
  height: 260px;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  transition: all 1s ease;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.flip-cards:hover {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.flip-cards div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 260px;
  position: absolute;    
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.front-card {
  z-index: auto;
}

.reverse-card {
  font-family: "Georgia";
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  background-color: black;
}

.reverse-card p {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #e5e5e5;
}

.reverse-card h2 {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #e5e5e5;
  text-align: center;
}

#card1 {background-image: url(http://placehold.it/200x260)}
#card2 {background-image: url(http://placehold.it/200x260)}
#card3 {background-image: url(http://placehold.it/200x260)}
#card4 {background-image: url(http://placehold.it/200x260)}
#card5 {background-image: url(http://placehold.it/200x260)}
```

```html
<div class="flip-container">
  <div class="flip-cards">
    <div class="front-card" id="card1"></div>
    <div class="reverse-card">
      <p>Text</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="flip-cards">
    <div class="front-card" id="card2"></div>
    <div class="reverse-card">
      <h2>About</h2>
      <p>Text</p> 
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="flip-cards">
    <div class="front-card" id="card3"></div>
    <div class="reverse-card">
      <p>Text</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="flip-cards">
    <div class="front-card"></div>
    <div class="reverse-card" id="card4fix">
      <p>Text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You forget to close "div" on card3.
You want to make it like this?
jsfiddle.net/8yjLnu3p

Comment: Oh my god thank you I feel so stupid! And here I was thinking it was my CSS.